# How do I make intellisense stop generating reduntant namespace qualifier?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, intellisense

I use VS2010 with Reshaper 5.1, but I have disabled Resharper intellisense so that I'm using the stock `VS2010` one (`Resharper>Options>Intellisense>General>Visual Studio`). Now, `VS2010` generates reduntant namespace qualifiers for Enums when it autocompletes assignment.

Illustration:

[image: Assigning an AccessibleRole for the MainForm. Note that I am using System.Windwos.Forms]

Result:

[image: Reduntant namespace for the AccessibleRole enum]

Why ? 
How do I fix it ? 
The `VS Tools>Options` dialog is a jungle of settings. I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a form context VS intellisense is attempting to disambiguate between:

```
AccessibleRole // implicitly this.AccessibleRole
```

and the enum.

The assignment works fine, but the intellisense is confused.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Intellisense didn't get confused with other enums - my config is  A-ok :-)

Comment: I have this same problem and your answer doesn't justify it as anything but a bug or "feature".  In the case of an enum it cannot be ambiguous because enums do not have members.  In the case of a class, there can be no ambiguity because a class cannot have a static member and an instance member of the same name.  This behavior (prefixing the namespace) is not present in Visual Studio 2005 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no way to turn this off, but a resharper clean command on the file will remove the redundant qualifiers.